# Put Linux Teminal in wxPython window

Tags: python, wxpython

I am beginner in wxPython, and I have two questions:

1. How can I put the Linux terminal in wxPython?
2. How do I connect the event, for example, of a combobox (or other) in Tabs (class1,class2,etc) to write text in TextControl (in class2)?

[image: example]

Comment: What do you mean by Linux Terminal? What do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

"The linux terminal" is a text console that needs to talk to a framebuffer or other display driver, so you're not going to be able to put that in a window without a whole lot of work.

But hopefully what you actually want is to just put any decent terminal in there—something you can run a shell in, ideally something that will match some TERMCAP entry so it can do things like curses, etc. You could build something like that yourself, but it's a lot of work. An easier solution is to use one of the pre-existing libraries for this, like [wxTerm](http://jeremysalwen.github.com/TerminalWx/classwxTerm.html).